# How to use the Server's IP address instead of mine?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2008

I've server(Windows Server 2008) in South Korea, and I'm living in California,so I configured VPN and NAT on it and now I have access to all files and folders on my Server, but my ip address is still from California, I wanna use the local internet too ,so is there any chance that I can use the Server's ip even for surfing the internet ? 
Actually I thinking about configure something like cisco anyconnect on it but unfortunately I coudn't find a good source for configuration.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your VPN is a split tunnel so it is only directing part (server traffic) of your traffic South Korea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your proxy, in this way you will surf the internet through your remote server.

Once you have running your VPN you have to change your browser settings.
For example in Google Chrome

```
1. Go to chrome://settings/
2. Click on Show advanced settings
3. Click on Change proxy settings
4. Now write your VPN's IP
```

I hope this can be more useful now.

Comment: How does one go that?

Comment: thanks but it won't work ,my ip is still from California, what port I have to set?